# Я добавляю картинки с помощью админ панель django но не отображается

Tags: django, изображения

Здравствуйте, я создал маленький сайт на django но когда хотел добавить картинки с помощью админ панель django не отображается но имя картинки показывает.

[image: Картинка на котором не отображается картинка]

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from news.models import Articles # Импорт база данных
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',
    ListView.as_view(queryset=Articles.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:20],
    template_name="news/posts.html")),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(model = Articles, template_name = "news/post.html"))
    # url(r'^$', 'news.views.news'),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() + static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
)
```

**post.html**

```
{% extends "mainApp/poisk.html" %}
from django.conf import settings

{% block content %}
  <h2 class="text-info">{{articles.title}}</h2>
  <h6 class="text-info">Опубликовано: {{articles.date|date:"Y-m-d в H:i:s"}}</h6>
  <p>{{articles.post|safe|linebreaks}}</p>
  <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ news.news_image.url}}">

{% endblock %}
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/media/'
```

**urls.py** в главном приложении

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('mainApp.urls')),
    url(r'^news/home/', include('mainApp.urls')),
    url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)#Максимальная длина строки 120
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='media/', help_text='150x150px', verbose_name='Ссылка картинки')

   def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В режиме dev-сервера необходимо добавить выдачу файлов Джангой. Файл **urls.py** при этом будет выглядеть так:

```js
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('mainApp.urls')),
    url(r'^news/home/', include('mainApp.urls')),
    url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```